# Boost Spirit QI: Limit dynmically number of parsed values

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I would like to parse data, which has the following format.

```
<numberOfAElements> <AElement1> <AElement2> <numberOfBElements> <BElement1> ...
```

Is it even possible to parse this format (without delimiters) using Boost Spirit?
I am thinking and googling about this problem for hours, but I have no solution yet.

I would be thankful for every idea.

Comment: Just adapt the last example from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/repeat.html)